# how to retrieve list of data from the firebase and to display it in table view?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase database look something like this

```
note-sam
  -KPwW5EmDbEFnlkz2XKm
      content: "abc"
      date: "2016/08/24 17:56"
      title: "there is"

  -KPwW8nXaZpx9dG59wbT
     content: "note"
     date: "2016/08/24 17:57"
     title: "first note"
```

my table view controller :

```
class TblViewController: UITableViewController {

var ref : FIRDatabaseReference!
var refHandle: UInt!
var noteList = [note]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    fetchUsers()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return noteList.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


    print(noteList[indexPath.row].title)
    cell.textLabel?.text = noteList[indexPath.row].title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = noteList[indexPath.row].date


    return cell
}

func fetchUsers()
{

     refHandl=ref.childByAutoId.observeEventType(.childAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
      if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
       {

            print(dictionary)

            let n_note = note()

            n_note.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
           self.noteList.append(n_note)

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                self.tableView.reloadData()
          })

       }

  })



}
```

}

My `note` class :-

```
class note: NSObject {

   var title: String?
   var content: String?
   var date: String?
}
```

Comment: didnt able to retrieve the data on tableview. and problem is fetch user function didnt call once after data saved to the db.

Comment: Try reloading it outside the async block, also did your `print(dictionary)` line get executed?Also try printing `noteList` in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** and check if it's OK?

Comment: Get rid of the dispatch_async as it's not needed. Change that observeEvent to .Value and loop through the values read in to populate your array datasource. When that loop is completed, call tableViewReload data.